# how can I get the video duration on YT API?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Hello guys I am using YT api for a some videos but I want to create some functions once the video is finished. There is any way to find how long is the video?

```
function onPlayerReady() {
  function updateTime() {
    var oldTime = videotime;
    if(player && player.getCurrentTime) {
      videotime = player.getCurrentTime();
    }
    if(videotime !== oldTime) {
      onProgress(videotime);
    }
  }
  timeupdater = setInterval(updateTime, 100);
}

// when the time changes, this will be called.
function onProgress(currentTime) {
    console.log(videotime)
    var halfway = (videotime / 2);
  if(currentTime == halfway) {
    counters("midpoint"); 
    console.log("the video has reached halfway!");
  }
}
```

This is what I am using to see the timing

Comment: Where do you call the YouTube API?

Comment: @Halcyon In another function and the YouTube API is bigger than this but I want to know find the length of the video

Answer (score 0):

Using the "videos" list API found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties). You want the "contentDetails" for the part property. Then it should be returned as contentDetails.duration

Comment: example? take a list is not an answer mate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many things you have to change.

- Remove updateTime() function, it's not necessary.
- Don't store variables like oldTime and videotime, to check for the player state just do `player.getPlayerState()`, 1 means 'playing'
- in `onProgress()` you're comparing calculating halfway as the videotime (currentTime) divided by 2, which is not a player duration.

Final and shortened code:

```
function onPlayerReady() {
  timeupdater = setInterval(function() {
    if (player.getPlayerState() == 1)
        onProgress(player);
  }, 100);
}

// when the time changes, this will be called.
function onProgress(p) {
  if(p.getCurrentTime() > p.getDuration() / 2) {
    // counters("midpoint"); 
    console.log("the video has reached halfway!");
  }
}
```

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/262hvvz8/)

Hope that worked for you :)